# Creating UIImageView with a tag. Swift 3

Tags: ios, swift, swift3, uiimageview

I have an int n that holds value. 
I want to create a loop that will create UIImageViews with consecutive tags.

My code:

```
var n:Int = 1
 if arrayOfEmojis.count != 0 {
        for emoji in arrayOfEmojis {

                let emojiView  = self.view.viewWithTag(n) as! UIImageView
                emojiView.image = emoji
                 ...

}
```

but the emojiView isn't created. 
When I use "if let emojiView = " it also just not created. 
Am i using "viewWithTag(n)" func wrong?

_______edit_________

was using `.viewWithTag()` wrong, had to just assign a tag with `.tag` property. 
However, now, I want to get that view using the tag that was assigned. 
I figured now i can use `.viewWithTag()` func? 
I get `unexpectedly found nil...` when calling :
(`n` was used in previous loop where imageViews was created, and it was updated to the number of imageViews that was created):

```
if arrayOfEmojis.count != 0 {
        for j in 1...n {

            var view1 = self.view.viewWithTag(j) as! UIImageView
            arrayOfEmojiViews.append(view1)
        }
    }
```

Comment: `viewWithTag(_:)` does not create anything - it simply returns an existing view within the view hierarchy that has a matching tag https://developer.apple.com/reference/uikit/uiview/1622429-viewwithtag

Comment: My guess - this edit is actually a new question - is that (1) you have nil using *viewWithTag* because nothing matches the value you are searching for. Why? (2) Possibly because your loop that creates the tag values sets the values *inside* a loop and *then* increments it. The net result is a **n** value that is +1 over any tag created.

Comment: yes, original question was answered by Ahmad. However, latter i need to use .viewWithTag() again. And it didn't work. 
Decided to update my question since it's on the same topic of .viewWithTag().

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you are misunderstanding the purpose of using [view​With​Tag(_:​)](https://developer.apple.com/reference/uikit/uiview/1622429-viewwithtag):

> Returns the view whose tag *matches the specified value*.

It does *not* create a new instance, it is used for getting a specific identified view based on its tag value.

If I am not mistaking, you want to create new instances, by mentioning:

> I want to create a loop that will *create UIImageViews* with
>   consecutive tags*.

It should be similar to:

```
var n:Int = 1
var currentTag = 0
if arrayOfEmojis.count != 0 {
    for emoji in arrayOfEmojis {

        let emojiView = UIImageView(image: emoji)
        emojiView.tag = currentTag
        currentTag += 1
        // don't forget to set the frame for the emojiView
        ...
    }
}
```

For each iteration, a new instance of [UIImageView](https://developer.apple.com/reference/uikit/uiimageview) will be created -by using [init(image:​)](https://developer.apple.com/reference/uikit/uiimageview/1621062-init) initializer- and setting its [tag](https://developer.apple.com/reference/uikit/uiview/1622493-tag) value "consecutively" based on the current value of `currentTag` variable.

Comment: it worked, thanks for explaining. 
However, down  the program, i have to use .viewWithTag again, now for getting views with that tag. I added that code to my original question. Would appreciate your advice.

Comment: Could you explain what's the new issue that you faced?

Comment: i'm creating imageViews out of images(emojis) that are in an array. This happens in viewDidLoad. 
Latter, i want to save not just images that are on the view but also their frames, since user have been panning, pinching and rotating those imageView. 
I want to save changed imageViews to the array. Inside the array, i'm trying to get imageViews by their tags, that were assigned at creation. 
And that is not happening, specifically in the line with '.viewWithTag()' line. You can find my code at the end of the original question.